# Array of images VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET. I am developing a game in which the user has to guess the name of the image that appears in a picturebox. The user has to enter the answer in a textbox. If it is right, a button appears and changes the image of the picturebox.

I would like the image of the picturebox to change when the next level button is clicked. I want to make an array which will contain all the images with a string as the answer.

How would I go about changing the image to the next in the array after each next level button click?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code you have already please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Load images to array

```
Dim imgPictures(8) As Image
imgPictures(0) = Bitmap.FromFile("Filename")
```

To display images.

```
Dim i as integer  = 0
```

Next Image

```
myPictureBox.Image = imgPictures(i++)
```

Previous Image

```
myPictureBox.Image = imgPictures(i--)
```

Make sure you are checking for maximum and minimum array values, otherwise you will get indexoutofrange exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will have a go at it and see if I need further help

Comment: i am getting an error at the end of myPictureBox.Image = imgPictures(i++) The error is "expression expected"

Comment: i replaced i++ with i+1 but it only works for the first image

Comment: Try this
i = i + 1
myPictureBox.Image = imgPictures(i)

Comment: thanks that worked but do u know why the picturebox on the first click displays the picture with the index value of 1 not 0

Comment: dont worry figured it out

Comment: is there a way to assign a string to these pictures? Because in my game i need to check the answer inputs by the user with the name of image

Comment: AFAIK pictures doesn't support any text information. Try changing the data type using Dictionay of string and image instead of image array. And if you resolved the issue, please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

*It's hard to tell exactly what parts of the code you need help with, so I'm guessing here. I went in a different direction than @Anuraj, which hopefully is helpful.*

Let's say you create an [object-based array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/object-array-vbnet):

```
Dim arr(10) As Object
```

You then create a `Sub` in your code that will handle the "next level" button's click event:

```
Private Sub NextLevelButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

'Do Stuff

End Sub
```

Now replace `'Do Stuff` with code that retrieves the next item in the array, and then changes the image in the UI. Obviously, to do this, you'll need to know which item in the array was most recently used. The easiest way to do this is to create a global variable (outside of all subs in your code) which you will replace each time you add a new image to the UI. The value of this global variable will be the index number of the most recently used image in your array. Then, you just increment by one and grab the next image.